# Javascript touchleave and touchcancel does not populate

Tags: javascript, jquery

Javascript touch events are like this: touchstart, touchend, touchmove, touchleave, touchcancel. I move my fingers on div element "#panel".

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#panel").on('touchstart', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#start-message").append("<p>Touch started</p>");
    });

    $("#panel").on('touchend', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#end-message").append("<p>Touch end</p>");
    });

    $("#panel").on('touchmove', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#move-message").append("<p>Touch moving...</p>");
    });     

    $("#panel").on('touchleave', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#leave-message").append("<p>Touch leaved.</p>");
    });

    $("#panel").on('touchcancel', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $("#cancel-message").append("<p>Touch cancelled.</p>");
    });
});
```

I am using Chrome F12 develper tool to simulate touch events. And I upload to server and try on mobile phone browser(not chrome). touchstart, touchend and touchend events are works fine. But I could not populate touchleave and touchcancel. [Working DEMO.](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/9wawaa1c/)

Comment: Test it in touch enable device.. _The touchcancel event is fired when a touch point has been disrupted in an implementation-specific manner (for example, too many touch points are created)._ [[Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchcancel)]

Comment: I updated the post.: I upload to server and try on mobile phone browser but does not work.

Comment: How do we test it ?

Comment: Test with https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/9wawaa1c/

Answer (score 1):

> From [*docs*](https://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#list-of-touchevent-types),
>   *A user agent must dispatch this `event` type to indicate when a touch point has been disrupted in an implementation-specific manner, such as a `synchronous event` or action originating from the `UA` canceling the touch, or the touch point leaving the `document window` into a `non-document area` which is capable of handling user interactions. (e.g. The UA's native user interface, plug-ins) A user agent may also dispatch this event type when the user places more touch points on the touch surface than the device or implementation is configured to store, in which case the earliest `Touch` object in the `TouchList` should be removed.*

From my personal experiments, invoke `touchcancel` in *`Chrome F12 develper tool`*, while `touchmove` handler in action, initiate <kbd>Right Click</kbd>

In Android *5.1*, Press `lock-key` or `Minimize-key` while `touchmove` handler is being invoked.

**Note:** Also refer [*Different ways to trigger touchcancel in mobile browsers*](https://alxgbsn.co.uk/2011/12/23/different-ways-to-trigger-touchcancel-in-mobile-browsers/)

For [***`touchleave`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchleave), *This `event` was a proposal in an early version of the `specification` and has not been implemented. Do not rely on it.[`From MDN`]*

Comment: Thanks Rayon, how does touchleave populate?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('touchstart',"#panel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#start-message").append("<p>Touch started</p>");
});

$(document).on('touchend',"#panel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#end-message").append("<p>Touch end</p>");
});

$(document).on('touchmove',"#panel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#move-message").append("<p>Touch moving...</p>");
});     

$(document).on('touchleave',"#panel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#leave-message").append("<p>Touch leaved.</p>");
});

$(document).on('touchcancel',"#panel", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#cancel-message").append("<p>Touch cancelled.</p>");
});});
```

Or please provide the working demo link for checking over there. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Two things to adjust here. Touch events work the same way as mouse events (more or less). Therefore you need to set active to **true** when touch starts and unset it when it ends / leaves / is canceled:

```
element.addEventListener('touchstart', function scrolling() {
       active = true;
       element.classList.add('scrolling');
});
```

Regarding your main issue - as I said touch events work **more or less** the same. If you log the touchmove event, you can see clientX stored under **e.touches[x].clientX**. The reason for this is quite simple - you have more than one finger.

```
element.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {
    if (!active) return;
    var x = e.touches[0].clientX;
    x -= element.querySelector('.wrapper').getBoundingClientRect().left;
    scrollIt(x, element);
});
```

**Edit:** I find it very useful to restart settings (in your case only 'active' variable) on orientation change, window size change, and when mouse leaves the context area.